# Ruby syntax error with declarative concept of using variable

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.2

I am trying to use the reactive programming concept in ruby, I have create two block of code:

## 1 Imperative

```
a = 5, b = 2
c = a + b
print c #=> 7

a = 2
print c #=> 7
```

## 2 Declarative

```
a := 5, b := 2
c := a + b
print c #=> 7

a := 2
print c #=> 4
```

However second example doesn't work for me and give the below error:

```
d.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
a := 5, b := 2
    ^
```

Please anyone help me to find out the error in the code. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

I know the second one is pseudo code but one thing surprise me that top score person make it off topic? The second code can also be executed using Reactive Library and top score programmer don't aware about it.

Comment: I have no clue, where you took the second snippet from, but it is simply incorrect ruby syntax.

Comment: Can you point me to the documentation of this feature?

Comment: Sir, it is the reactive programming approach used by ruby 2.2 please have a look over it https://www.zweitag.de/en/blog/technology/functional-reactive-programming-frp

Comment: @Зелёный https://www.zweitag.de/en/blog/technology/functional-reactive-programming-frp

Comment: You should read this article carefully, The following example in **pseudo-code** shows the key difference between both paradigms.

Comment: Thanks however first example is working fine

Comment: @Зелёный Is there any way to use and see the difference between these two

Comment: Thanks for your help, so I have to think or assume everything theoretically. No way to understand this new approach.

Comment: I know the second one is pseudo code but one thing surprise me that top score person make it off topic? The second code can also be executed using Reactive Library and top score programmer don't aware about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:=` is not valid Ruby.

The error message is because symbols are represented by leading colons so `:example` is a symbol (compare to `"example"` which is a string).

So encountering `:` Ruby expects a valid beginning character for a symbol, which would be any of...

```
@$_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Middle characters can be...

```
_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
```

And the last character can be...

```
!_=?ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
```

So `=` is never a valid symbol character.

The article you reference is showing pseudo-code not actual Ruby.

Comment: Any other way to differentiate between imperative & declarative approach.

Comment: I know the second one is pseudo code but one thing surprise me that top score person make it off topic? The second code can also be executed using Reactive Library and top score programmer don't aware about it.

Comment: You're talking about ReactiveX ?  It's not really adaptable to the pseudo-code you were trying to run.  Basically, it was off-topic because you misunderstood the syntax of Ruby.  There is a good, fundamental question there, but phrased badly.  Instead of "why doesn't `c := a + b` work?" you could've asked "how can I code `c = a + b` so that `c` dynamically changes when `a` or `b` changes?"

Comment: Could you please edit the question instead of off topic.